# How to compute cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking to compute cardinals such without using directly the theorems (or else a trivial exercise)
I do not want to be given the answer but is it correct that I have to find a cardinal smaller and a cardinal greater and show they are equal?
I worked that:
${\mathfrak {c}} \leq   {\mathfrak {c}}n^{\aleph _0} \leq {\aleph _0}^{\aleph _0}$
Now is it that  all I must show is that $ {\aleph _0}^{\aleph _0} =   {\mathfrak {c}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Why should $\mathfrak c n^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$?  If $\mathfrak c$ were greater than $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ the comparison would be false.  The usual proof is 
$$\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$$

Comment: than Because cnN0 = 2^N0 n^N0 = (2n)^N0<= N0^N0

Comment: OK, but I think you need to show those steps

Comment: And is that sufficient for my question do you think? One other question, for an ordinal n of a finite set A I know  N0 <= n N0 <=N0 N0 = N0 and so I know n N0 = N0. I'm struggling to show this for the continuum. I have c <=nc <=N0 c <= N0 2^N0 but I don't know the next step to show N0 2^N0 <= c

Comment: We usually use $\omega$ for the first infinite ordinal.  It is not true that $\omega^\omega=\omega$.  They are equal cardinalities, but using $\omega$ tells us to use original exponentiation, not cardinal exponentiation.